# Delete ConvertView Run Time in BaseAdapter using listview

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, mediastore, audio

I am working on application that retrieve all audio-files(with album-art) dynamically at getView() method of BaseAdapter.

now how can i delete item on touch of listView.
(e.g if i click on 3rd item of listView, 3rd item should be deleted or removed).

**music_cursor code** :

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE };

Cursor musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        proj, null, null, null);
int count = musiccursor.getCount();
```

**Adapter code :**

```
public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public MusicAdapter(Context con) {
            mContext = con;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            String id = null;
            ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.ID_ = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);
                holder.SIZE_ = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSongSize);
                holder.ARTIST = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSongArtist);
                holder.TITLE_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgArtWork);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // code for retrieving audio name and set to textView
            music_column_index = musiccursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
            id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
            holder.ID_.setText(id);
            holder.ID_.setTextSize(15);

            // code for retrieving audioSize and set to textView
            music_column_index = musiccursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
            id = (musiccursor.getString(music_column_index) + " (KB)");
            holder.SIZE_.setText(id);
            holder.SIZE_.setTextSize(15);

            // code for retrieving audio_Artist name and set to textView
            music_column_index = musiccursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
            id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
            holder.ARTIST.setText(id);
            holder.ARTIST.setTextSize(15);

            // code for retrieving album-art(from albumid) and set to ImageView

            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
            album_id_long = musiccursor.getLong(musiccursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id_long);
            ContentResolver res = MusicActivity.this.getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = res.openInputStream(uri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            holder.TITLE_image.setImageBitmap(artwork);

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //on this code of onClick,a selected item should be deleted

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView ID_;
            TextView SIZE_;
            TextView ARTIST;
            ImageView TITLE_image;
        }
    }
```

[image]

If there is another way to do this.
that will be strongly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have to override

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

when you click on a view, this callback will be invoked. When it is invoked you can delete the entry from your DB, and re run the  query you create to fill up your `ListView`. If you are exteding `Activity` instead of `ListActivity`, you have to set the `OnItemClickListener`

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(
    new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {


             }
        }
 );
```

Comment: i didn't do that @blackbelt

Comment: onListItemClick can't be override anyware in the class,what should i do.@blackbelt ??

Comment: are you extending activtity or ListActivity?

Comment: I edited my answer. If I could suggest you, When you manage cursor and ListView you should use the CursorAdapter and CursorLoader

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want to delete the music file or simply remove it from the ListView?
By the way, you only need to call
"musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);"
once at the start

Comment: actually i want both operation.but for that,at first i have to remove item from listView first.i was also able to remove with fix arrayAdapter , but now files are coming from getViw area.here m not able to handle delete operation.